# Does the JavaScript typeof operator ever return an upper case string?

Tags: javascript

I recently came across the following line of code:

```
var type = (typeof x).toLowerCase();
```

Note that in the above code, `x` will only ever be a string, a number, or undefined. I questioned this, pointing out that the [specification (11.4.3)](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3) states the values to be returned by the `typeof` operator, and all of them are already lower case.

It's worth noting that the specification leaves host objects free to return pretty much whatever they like, so in that case it *is* possible to get a string with some upper case letters (I don't whether that actually ever happens, but it is allowed). However, as already stated, in this case `x` is only ever a string, a number or undefined.

My question is, do any implementations of the `typeof` operator ever return anything other than a lower case string?

Comment: It will always return a string, as »Return a String determined by Type(val) according to Table 20.« shows.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but I was assured that there was a reason for the line of code in question. I disagree, but want to be sure before I remove it. Do any implementations deviate from the spec?

Comment: Take nothing for granted with JS, there's always some jackass implementation that doesn't follow things to the letter. It's not like the specifications are overly clear most the time either. At the end of the day, the cost of doing `toLowerCase()` is trivial and is safer than not doing it.

Comment: @Thor84no that's stupid. `toLowerCase` is bullshit code on numbers strings or undefined unless it comes from a host object. And besides the same jackass implementation can return an upper case string when you call `.toLowerCase`

Comment: @Raynos - I was thinking the same. I will be removing the call to `toLowerCase` and pointing the author of that code to the spec, which was already enough for me to believe it was unnecessary, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Raynos You seriously think it more likely that an implementation will return upper case strings from the call `toLowerCase` (lets be fair, that's a pretty well understood function), than that an implementation will return "Object" instead of "object" from a `typeof` call? I never said it *should* be needed, only that it won't do any harm and just may save you an obscure bug if this code is run on an unusual JS implementation.

Comment: @Thor84no no I think both are stupidly unlikely. the chance of both is so stupidly neglible that they both fall in the same order of magnitude of probability.

Comment: @Raynos There's really no need to be so confrontational. There are far more stupid inconsistencies than returning different case strings in the JS world.

Comment: @Thor84no calling `toLowerCase` borders more on programming by coincidence then on defensive programming. Encouraging people to write code like that is not a good thing.

Comment: @Raynos I wasn't so much encouraging him to write code like this as I was encouraging to not remove such code he randomly found without talking to the person who wrote it as there *could* be a reason someone did it. It's also far from programming by "coincidence" to *make sure* values are of the format you expect them to be in.

Comment: @Thor84no it is programming by coincidence if you don't already know the format the value is in.

Comment: @Raynos The whole point of this is that if you don't control which implementations interpret the code then you don't actually *know* until you've tried it in all of them. In other words it's impossible to guarantee it 100%, however unlikely you might find it.

Comment: @Thor84no and it's impossible to garauntee `toLowerCase` returns a lower case string 100% of the time however unlikely you might find it.

Comment: Except if `typeof` returns "Object", someone didn't care enough to check what case it was, thought they already knew, or otherwise made a mistake. If `toLowerCase` returns an upper case string as you mentioned it's malicious. You can continue your ridiculous bashing if you wish, but this has already gone on for too long so I'm leaving it from now.

Comment: if it ever does return an uppercase string it will be for a type that is not one of those listed in the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spidermonkey seems to return only these:

```
"undefined"
"object"
"function"
"string"
"number"
"boolean"
NULL
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_GetTypeName

The same with V8:

```
default:
  // For any kind of object not handled above, the spec rule for
  // host objects gives that it is okay to return "object"
  return isolate->heap()->object_symbol();
```

http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/runtime.cc#5245

No idea about MS, I guess they don't use custom typeof either, but you never know with them.

> There are six possible values that typeof returns: "number," "string," "boolean," "object," "function," and "undefined."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/259s7zc1%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: [See IE extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955290(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

return values for the typeof operator

> Undefined: "undefined"
>   Null: "object"
>   Boolean: "boolean"
>   Number: "number"
>   String: "string"
>   Object (native and doesn't implement Call): "object"
>   Object (native and implements Call): "function"
>   Object (host): Implementation-dependent

So yes except the last.
[Source](http://www.quora.com/In-JavaScript-does-typeof%28SOMETHING%29-always-return-a-lowercase-string-or-does-it-differ-between-browsers)

Comment: This is just the table that's in the spec (linked to in the question). I want to know if any implementations ever deviate from the spec.

Answer (score 0):

As per [extensions to typeof operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

IE9 returns

- "unknown" for SafeArray
- "data" for VarDate

Both of which are non-standard types defined by host objects

older IEs are also known for returning "unknown" for various other host objects.