# Is it necessary to call `toLowerCase()` after each `typeof`?

Tags: javascript

I've come across the following piece of Javascript code:

```
if ((typeof callback).toLowerCase() === 'function')
```

Is calling `toLowerCase()` after each `typeof` necessary? Or is it simply clutter?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof read the table of possible types (all lower)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8941278/724591

Answer (score 4):

No no no no no no no no no no no no no.

In *most* cases `typeof` resolves to a [small list](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) of known, all-lowercase values.

Comment: @bfavaretto: not only sense of humour, but they probably don't know SO answer limitations :-)

Answer (score 1):

All the strings returned by `typeof` are always in lower case. However `typeof` is not very accurate. Instead I recommend that you use `Object.prototype.toString` instead for the reasons mentioned in this article: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof

```
function typeOf(value) {
    if (value === null) return "Null";
    if (typeof value === "undefined") return "Undefined";
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1);
}
```

The above `typeOf` function is a fix for the `typeof` operator. It always returns the correct type of the value passed to it. For example `typeOf([])` returns `"Array"` whereas `typeof []` returns `"object"`. You can use `toLowerCase` on the `typeOf` function.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to use `.toLowerCase()`.

`.toLowerCase()` is used to make all characters in a string lowercase.

`typeof`, on the other hand, returns the value of the operand.

Comment: Your answer explains **nothing**

Comment: No. The `typeof` operator returns the type of the operand as a lower case string. Hence you don't need to call `toLowerCase` on it.

Comment: @Aadit M Shah: "the type of the operand as a lower case string" --- it would be nice if someone put a reference to a specification

Comment: @zerkms Care to do the honors? I've been reading through my college textbook all day to prepare for an exam and I really don't want to read the JavaScript specs right now.

Comment: @Aadit M Shah: I didn't mention you explicitly. But without reference "the type of the operand as a lower case string" looks not reputable enough

Comment: @zerkms Well all the type strings in the specification are all lower case: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3 However it leaves the type of host objects for the implementation to decide and that could potentially be upper case for certain implementations. In my opinion however most implementations would be sensible enough to keep it lower case.